# How to get product collection in specific created CMS block?

Tags: magento2

In my `InstallData.php` file I have created a CMS block, like:

```
private function createCmsBlock()
{
    $blockData = [
        'title' => 'Title',
        'identifier' => 'Identifier',
        'stores' => [0],
        'is_active' => 1,
    ];
    $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($blockData)->save();
}
```

I want to retrieve a product collection in my block. I'm trying to retrieve it as:

```
private function getProductsCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3);
    return $collection;
}
```

But the question is where do I have to put `getProductsCollection()` function in my code to get it in my block?

Comment: you want collection into CMS block?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes